# Apply Oracle query to list of tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of tables in an Oracle instance labeled 'TableA_101818', 'TableB_101818', etc. and I would like to update all of those tables in a single query. I know I can get the list of tables using:

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818'
```

but I'm not sure how to apply something like:

```
UPDATE (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818) 
SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for all tables the updated strings are identical, you may very easy produce an update script using this SQL.

```
select   
'UPDATE "'||TABLE_NAME||q'[" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else';]' update_sql
from user_tables where table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818'; 

UPDATE "Table1_101818" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else';
UPDATE "Table2_101818" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else';
```

Just copy the produced lines in your used SQL tool and run it.

*Note, that in case that your tabele names are in *mixed case* you must quote the in the generated query.

If you want to check the previos value (before the  update), simple add the predicate in the `WHERE`condition.

```
select   
'UPDATE "'||TABLE_NAME||q'[" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else' and COL1 = 'previous value';]' update_sql
from user_tables where table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818';


UPDATE "Table1_101818" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else' and COL1 = 'previous value';
UPDATE "Table2_101818" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else' and COL1 = 'previous value';
```

In case that there is a diferent *previos value* in `COL1` you will see `0 records updated` and no chnage will be done.

The most general case is when the values to be updated differs for each table.

You may set up a helper table  containg table name and the values and use it in the query producing the update statements:

```
TABLE_NAME                     COL1                           COL1_OLD                       COL2                         
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
Table1_101818                  something                      previous value                 something else                 
Table2_101818                  z                              y                              x
```

The query joins to the helper table and gets the proper values for each table

```
select   
'UPDATE "'||a.TABLE_NAME||'" SET COL1 = '''||b.col1||''' WHERE COL2 = '''||
    b.col2||''' and COL1 = '''||b.col1_old||''';' update_sql
from user_tables a
join update_values b on a.table_name = b.table_name
where a.table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818';

UPDATE "Table1_101818" SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE COL2 = 'something else' and COL1 = 'previous value';
UPDATE "Table2_101818" SET COL1 = 'z' WHERE COL2 = 'x' and COL1 = 'y';
```

Note that this approach works fine for limited number of tables to be processed in a single step. If you have tons of tables or the task is periodical you will want to go the *dynamic SQL* approach explained in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
begin
  for r in (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables 
            WHERE table_name LIKE 'Table%_101818') 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('SELECT * FROM ' || r.table_name ||
                         q'{ WHERE col2 = 'something else';}');

    execute immediate 'UPDATE ' || r.table_name ||
                      q'{ SET COL1 = 'something' WHERE col2 = 'something else'}';
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help, Could you tell me how I could first select * from the tables? I want to make sure the records I'm changing are in fact those that need

Comment: @DgBridge You could use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to print  values and exchange `UPDATE` with `SELECT`

Comment: So I used this:

`BEGIN
 for r in (select table_name from all_tables where table_name like 'Table%_%101818%')
 loop
  execute IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM '|| r.TABLE_NAME || q'{WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL;}';
 end loop;
 COMMIT;
END;
/`

And unfortunately got an error saying it was not properly ended

Comment: @DB Print first only `SELECT` statements, copy to second window and run.

Comment: When I type in `SELECT * FROM "TableA_101818" WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL` I get the proper response